# Ruby REGEX split, any issues with the code

Tags: ruby, regex

I am a rookie in Regex for Ruby. I read some tutorials and evaluated a piece of code.
Please let me know if I can do it in a better way.

Here is my text which needs to be split at {iwsection(*)} and {{usersection}}

```
    t='{{iwsection(1)}}
    This has some sample text 1 - line 1
    This has some sample text 1 - line 2
    {{iwsection(2)}}
    This has some sample text 2
    {{iwsection(3)}}
    This has some sample text 3
    {{usersection}}
    This is a user section.
    This has some sample text
    This has some sample text'
```

Here is the ruby regex code I was able to manage.

```
    t.split(/^({{[i|u][wsection]\w*...}})/)
```

Thank You.

The Desired Output :
A array as,

```
    [ '{{iwsection(1)}}', 'This has some sample text 1\nThis has some sample text 1 - line 2',
    '{{iwsection(2)}}', 'This has some sample text 2',
    '{{iwsection(3)}}', 'This has some sample text 3',
    '{{usersection}}', 'This is a user section\nThis has some sample text\nThis has some sample text.']
```

With this I will build a Hash,

```
    { 
    '{{iwsection(1)}}' => 'This has some sample text 1\nThis has some sample text 1 - line 2',
    '{{iwsection(2)}}' => 'This has some sample text 2',
    '{{iwsection(3)}}' => 'This has some sample text 3',
    '{{usersection}}' => 'This is a user section\nThis has some sample text\nThis has some sample text.'
    }
```

**Edit:** .....

The code.

```
    section_array = text.chomp.split(/\r\n|\n/).inject([]) do |a, v|
    if v =~ /{{.*}}/
      a << [v.gsub(/^{{|}}$/, ""), []]
    else
      a.last[1] << v
    end
    a
    end.select{ |k, v| (k.start_with?("iwsection") || k.start_with?("usersection")) }.map{ |k, v| ["{{#{k}}}", v.join("\n")] }
```

Comment: Whats your desired output array? Please post an example of what you would want the results to look like.

Comment: You shouldn't have the Rails tag here, as this is a pure-Ruby question. Having a superfluous tag may cause some to waste time, others (who filter out Rails questions) to not see the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. I somehow missed this.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan The desired output updated..

Comment: Depending on what you are actually trying to do, it looks like either a config parser (e.g. [parseconfig](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/parseconfig)) or a templating solution (e.g. [Mustache](https://github.com/mustache/mustache)) could possibly solve your problem in a cleaner way.

Comment: Please do not modify your question (except for minor fixes like typos). The edits you have done render answers meaningless. If you wish to clarify or add additional requirements (the latter is generally discouraged), leave your question as is and add text that is identified as an edit.  Some SO members write `**Edit:** ....`. I suggest you roll you question back to an earlier version, then add the changes you have made.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : point noted. Thank You. There is not much change from the initial request, The regex was not feasible for my requirement.

Comment: I modified by my to answer to address your additional requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
> t.scan(/{{([^}]*)}}\r?\n(.*?)\r?(?=\n{{|\n?$)/)
=> [["iwsection(1)", "This has some sample text 1"], ["iwsection(2)", "This has some sample text 2"], ["iwsection(3)", "This has some sample text 3"], ["usersection", "This is a user section."]]

> h = t.scan(/{{([^}]*)}}\r?\n(.*?)\r?(?=\n{{|\n?$)/).to_h
=> {"iwsection(1)"=>"This has some sample text 1", "iwsection(2)"=>"This has some sample text 2", "iwsection(3)"=>"This has some sample text 3", "usersection"=>"This is a user section."}

> h.values
=> ["This has some sample text 1", "This has some sample text 2", "This has some sample text 3", "This is a user section."]

> h.keys
=> ["iwsection(1)", "iwsection(2)", "iwsection(3)", "usersection"]

> h["usersection"]
=> "This is a user section."
```

#### Update:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
t = "{{iwsection(1)}}\nThis has some sample text 1 - line 1\nThis has some sample text 1 - line 2\n{{iwsection(2)}}\nThis has some sample text 2\n{{iwsection(3)}}\nThis has some sample text 3\nThis has some sample text\nThis has some sample text\n{{usersection}}\nThis is a user section.\nThis has some sample text\nThis has some sample text"
h = t.chomp.split(/\n/).inject([]) do |a, v|
  if v =~ /{{.*}}/
    a << [v.gsub(/^{{|}}$/, ""), []]
  else
    a.last[1] << v
  end
  a
end.select{ |k, v| k.start_with? "iwsection" or k === "usersection" }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.join("\n")] }.to_h
puts h.inspect
```

Output:

```
{"iwsection(1)"=>"This has some sample text 1 - line 1\nThis has some sample text 1 - line 2", "iwsection(2)"=>"This has some sample text 2", "iwsection(3)"=>"This has some sample text 3\nThis has some sample text\nThis has some sample text", "usersection"=>"This is a user section.\nThis has some sample text\nThis has some sample text"}
```

Comment: Wow..!! I did not know about this method in String class. I will give it a try. This actually fits my desired output.

Comment: Looks like this , scans any text between {{}} and prepares a array/hash. Can we limit this to only text with "iwsection" and "usersection"

Comment: @rupeshj Rather than making the regex dirty, just `select()` needed text instead: `t.scan(/{{([^}]*)}}\r?\n(.*?)\r?(?=\n{{|\n?$)/).select{ |k, v| k.start_with? "iwsection" || k == "usersection" }`

Comment: Sure, Thanks. I will use select.

Comment: This one captures only one line, I am not getting the result when I have multiple lines in the section. :(

Comment: @rupeshj I made an update. Looks like `String#scan` may not be enough.

Comment: Great, It worked. Thank You, But a small correction on ruby 2.1 to_h failed. Not sure why, And modified a little at the splitting -- \n| \r\n

Comment: @rupeshj What changes did you made? Can you place them around backquotes so I could read them well?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
t.split(/{{iwsection\(\d+\)}}|{{usersection}}/)
  #=> ["", "\n    This has some sample text 1\n    ",
  #    "\n    This has some sample text 2\n    ",
  #    "\n    This has some sample text 3\n    ",
  #    "\n    This is a user section."]
```

That's what you asked for, but if you want to clean that up, add `.map(&:strip)`:

```
t.split(/{{iwsection\(\d+\)}}|{{usersection}}/).map(&:strip).map(&:strip)
  #=> ["", "This has some sample text 1", "This has some sample text 2",
  #    "This has some sample text 3", "This is a user section."]
```

You may not want the empty string at offset zero, but that's how [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) works when you are splitting on a substring that is at the beginning of the string.  Suppose the string were instead:

```
t =
'Some text here{{iwsection(1)}}
This has some sample text 1
{{iwsection(2)}}
This has some sample text 2'

t.split(/{{iwsection\(\d+\)}}|{{usersection}}/).map(&:strip).map(&:strip)
  #=> ["Some text here", "This has some sample text 1",
  #    "This has some sample text 2"]
```

Here you want "Some text here", so you can't just delete the first element of the array.

**Additional requirements**

To satisfied your added requirement, you could do this:

```
t='{{iwsection(1)}}
Text 1 - line 1
Text 1 - line 2
{{iwsection(2)}}
Text 2
{{iwsection(3)}}
Text 3
{{usersection}}
User section.
Text
Text' 

h = t.scan(/(?:{{iwsection\(\d+\)}}|{{usersection}})/)
     .zip(t.split(/{{iwsection\(\d+\)}}|{{usersection}}/)[1..-1])
     .map { |s1,s2| [s1, s2.strip
                           .lines
                           .map(&:strip)
                           .join("\n")] }
     .to_h
  #=> {"{{iwsection(1)}}"=>"Text 1 - line 1\nText 1 - line 2",
  #    "{{iwsection(2)}}"=>"Text 2",
  #    "{{iwsection(3)}}"=>"Text 3",
  #    "{{usersection}}"=>"User section.\nText\nText"}
```

Note that this formatting may not be understood by IRB or PRY, but will work fine from the command line.

*Explanation*

```
a = t.scan(/(?:{{iwsection\(\d+\)}}|{{usersection}})/)
  #=> ["{{iwsection(1)}}", "{{iwsection(2)}}", "{{iwsection(3)}}", "{{usersection}}"]
b = t.split(/{{iwsection\(\d+\)}}|{{usersection}}/)
  #=> ["", "\n    Text 1 - line 1\n    Text 1 - line 2\n    ",
  #    "\n    Text 2\n    ", "\n    Text 3\n    ",
  #    "\n    User section.\n    Text\n    Text"]
c = b[1..-1]
  #=> ["\n    Text 1 - line 1\n    Text 1 - line 2\n    ",
  #    "\n    Text 2\n    ", "\n    Text 3\n    ",
  #    "\n    User section.\n    Text\n    Text"]
h = a.zip(c)
  #=> [["{{iwsection(1)}}", "\n    Text 1 - line 1\n    Text 1 - line 2\n    "],
  #    ["{{iwsection(2)}}", "\n    Text 2\n    "],
  #    ["{{iwsection(3)}}", "\n    Text 3\n    "],
  #    ["{{usersection}}", "\n    User section.\n    Text\n    Text"]]
d = h.map { |s1,s2| [s1, s2.strip
                           .lines
                           .map(&:strip)
                           .join("\n")] }
  #=> [["{{iwsection(1)}}", "Text 1 - line 1\nText 1 - line 2"],
  #    ["{{iwsection(2)}}", "Text 2"], ["{{iwsection(3)}}", "Text 3"],
  #    ["{{usersection}}", "User section.\nText\nText"]]
d.to_h
  #=> {"{{iwsection(1)}}"=>"Text 1 - line 1\nText 1 - line 2",
  #    "{{iwsection(2)}}"=>"Text 2",
  #    "{{iwsection(3)}}"=>"Text 3",
  #    "{{usersection}}"=>"User section.\nText\nText"}
```

Comment: How can I retain the iwsection or at the number inside iwsection/usersection when I split it ?